# Automatically double an iPhone view on an iPad without a user doing it

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard, screen

When a user uses an iPhone app on the iPad, they have the option to double the view to fit the iPad. My application has over 100 view controllers  and 800 segues. Is there an app delegate api or line of code that I can use to automatically do this for the user (the interface would be iPad friendly despite not having any over-rated split views)?

Comment: This question was answered previously on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680392/developing-iphone-app-to-run-on-ipad-auto-set-2x

Comment: Not all iPad apps have those "over-rated" split views.

Answer (score 0):

The interface would not be iPad friendly as all of your graphics pixel resolutions would be halved (as would the built-in UI pixel resolutions - the 2x setting just does pixel-doubling).

You can make an iPad-friendly interface by designing for the iPad. At very least all you need to do is ensure appropriate settings in autolayout or using autoresizing masks, with no need for a separate storyboard or separate xibs. But you would need to do at least that. iPad design does not come for free.